# How to use append to add a li to a ul in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, append

I am just starting out with web development and have got the basics of css and html under my belt and have begun to learn jQuery. I tried to use my new found skills to make a website where you typed in a phrase into a text box and click add and it would add it to a list.

There are other similar questions but for me they seem really complicated, all I want to do is add the text from the box to a ul. I cannot see why my code is not working and I was wondering if someone could help.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="addThis"/>
<div id="button"><a href="#">Add</a></div>

<h2>My List:</h2>
<div id="toDoList">
    <ul id="list">
        <!--This is the TODO list-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=addThis]').val();
        $("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>").appendTo("#list");
    });
});
```

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/dUrvP/

Comment: have you already tried to do the other way?
$("#list").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");

Comment: I also would suggest (as a cleaner and *safer* alternative): `("#list").append($("<li>").text(toAdd));`

Comment: Have you included the Jquery files in your code? Is there any error you are getting in the console??

Comment: I have tried everything that has been mentioned and it still won't work! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and switch the order.

```
$("#list").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem.

Check you have added any `version` of `jquery`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=addThis]').val();
        $("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>").appendTo("#list");
    });
}); 
</script>
```